# Twitter Bootstrap - how to render navbar-dropdown opened?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I have dropdown list on navbar. I'm using Jade template engine, that's why my code is:

```
a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown') Login
ul.dropdown-menu
  li
    form.well(action="/login", method="post")
      label Your e-mail:
      input.span3(type='text', placeholder='e-mail', name="username")
      label Your password:
      input.span3(type='password', placeholder='*************', name="password")
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Login now »
```

I'd like to render this dropdown list opened to show login error. How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Jade template engine - however, if you add `class="open"` to the containing element (not provided in your excerpt), the dropdown will render in the open state.

I imagine it would look something like:

```
li.dropdown.open
  a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown') Login
  ul.dropdown-menu
    li
      form.well(action="/login", method="post")
        label Your e-mail:
        input.span3(type='text', placeholder='e-mail', name="username")
        label Your password:
        input.span3(type='password', placeholder='*************', name="password")
        button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Login now »
```